# Unhandled rejection error after removing item from localstorage. Refresh fixes it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax-error, local-storage

So I am trying to put a logout button on my site, and I have the user's token stored in localstorage, but when the logout button is clicked, and the token is removed from localstorage, as soon as the site redirects back to the login page, I get the error `Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0`

It only does this once per logout. If you refresh the page,it loads just fine, but obviously nobody wants errors like this on their site.

The token is stored after logging in like this:

```
async userLogin(e) {
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    const target = e.target.value
    try {
      let response = await fetch("<API URL removed for security reasons>", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email: email,
          password: password,
          uid: email
        })
      });
      let res = await response.text();
      if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
        let accessToken = res;
        console.log(accessToken);
        localStorage.setItem("access_token", accessToken);
        this.setState({
          loginFailed: false,
          isFlipped: true,
        });
      } else {
        let error = res;
        this.setState({
          loginFailed: true
        });
        alert("Invalid login credentials");
        throw error;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({
        error: error,
        loginFailed: true
      });
      console.log("error: " + error);

    }
  }
```

`localStorage.setItem("access_token", accessToken);` is where the token is stored. I remove the token using `localStorage.removeItem("access_token")` I have also tried using `localStorage.clear()` but it gives the same error when returning to the login screen. All I am doing when the logout button is pressed is deleting the token and redirecting to the login screen, it's nothing complex.

```
 const logOut = () => {
    localStorage.clear()
    console.log(localStorage)
    return <Redirect to="/login"/>
  }
```

The error comes when the root page parses the localstorage to check for a token. Here is the source of the error message:

```
  componentWillMount() {
    const hasToken = JSON.parse(localStorage.access_token)
    if (hasToken.token_info.token !== null) {
      this.setState({
        authenticated: true
      })
    }   
  }
```

Comment: before you parse check make sure it's not undefined . `if(localStorage.access_token!===undefined){
    const hasToken = JSON.parse(localStorage.access_token)

}`

Comment: Is `userLogin` an event handler? Why is `Accept: "application/json"` header set at client? Is `.catch()` chained to `userLogin()` function to handle error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because `localStorage.access_token` returns `undefined` and parsing `undefined` with `JSON.parse` throws error. So you could check as

`const hasToken = localStorage.access_token ? JSON.parse(localStorage.access_token) : null`

Comment: I did try that before, but then it gave me the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'token_info' of null` -- but then I just realized that token_info won't exist if hasToken is null, so I had it check against `hasToken` for null instead of `hasToken.token_info.token` and it seems to work! Thanks!

Comment: yeah it will be because `hasToken` is null so you could check as `if (hasToken && hasToken.token_info.token !== null) {}`

Comment: yea, I guess I didn't notice it because I'm a bit sleep deprived -- got a deadline tomorrow! I knew it was gonna end up being something really simple haha